SharePoint Server 2019 goes very slow after sometime
I freshly setup a SharePoint 2019 server with three tier architecture (FE, APP and DB). Sometime it run fast the page load immediately but on the very next minute if refresh the page or open the URL in new tab it become very slow. The tab show " Waiting for response for
SharePoint server" and it just keep loading for next 1 minutes or so. And while its showing loading if I copy paste the URL in another tab it get open there immediately. It is happening with all site including the CA.
I did some looking in my environment:

All three server are running between  40-50% avg. RAM, CPU and Disk utilization
There are packet drops showing while pinging to AD Server.
Also I look at the network monitoring under the browser inspect element, whenever the page is taking time to load its showing and "401 Unauthorized" under result column of edge browser.
While doing the SharePoint config wizard, I ran it on the App server first so it took the server URL address of APP server instead on FE server.


There are several factors that could be contributing to the slow performance of your SharePoint Server 2019 setup. Here are some potential issues and troubleshooting steps:
Network Issues: The packet drops you mentioned while pinging the Active Directory (AD) server could indicate network instability. This can lead to delays in authentication and other requests, causing slow page loads.
401 Unauthorized Errors: The "401 Unauthorized" errors in the network monitoring could suggest that there are authentication issues. This might be related to the configuration of your SharePoint environment, especially if the configuration wizard was run on the App server instead of the Front End (FE) server.
Server Load: Although your servers are running at 40-50% utilization, it’s worth checking if there are any spikes in resource usage during peak times or if there are background processes affecting performance.
Browser Configuration: Ensure that your browser settings are optimized for SharePoint. This includes adding the SharePoint Central Administration site to trusted sites and disabling any unnecessary security settings that might impede performance.
Caching Issues: Consider whether caching is properly configured. If the server is making multiple requests for the same resources, it could slow down page loads.
